# SQL Server: Joining Tables where table 2 has multiple entries for same primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, syntax-error, left-join

I am trying to join two tables.

Table1 contains the following relevant information

1. AccountID_T1
2. Information

Table2 contains the following relevant information

- AccountID_T2
- AccountName

In both tables, the same AccountID will yield different information. For example, the command:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
  WHERE AccountID_T1 = '1234'
```

Will yield a table like this:

| AccountID_T1 | Information |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | This happened today |
| 1234 | This happened yesterday |

In Table2, the command:

```
SELECT * FROM Table2
      WHERE AccountID_T2 = '1234'
```

Will yield a table like this:

| AccountID_T2 | AccountName |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | Client A |
| 1234 | Client A |
| 1234 | Client A International |

The objective is to join Table 1 and Table 2 on AccountID as a primary key so the query yields a table with AccountID, Information, and AccountName.

When I attempt the following command:

```
LEFT JOIN Table1 ON AccountID_T1=AccountID_T2
```

the "LEFT JOIN" command is greyed out and I get the error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LEFT'.

I'm not sure how to resolve this problem; I'm thinking it has something to do with the multiple instances of primary keys in one or both of the tables and/or that Table2 will often have different values for the same primary key (i.e: Client A and Client A International both having AccountID 1234).

I am not very well versed in SQL so apologies if I am leaving out any context.

Comment: Primary keys are always ***unique***.  Your question does not make sense.

Comment: You haven't shown what your expected results are, nor your complete query.

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LEFT'. usually means there is a syntax error prior to LEFT but you don't show the rest of the statement.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question well enough but please try the following query.

```
SELECT 
T1.ACCOUNTID_T1,
T1.INFORMATION,
T2.ACCOUNTNAME
FROM TABLE1 T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
TABLE2 T2 ON T1.ACCOUNTID_T1=T2.ACCOUNTID_T2
```